# Codesniffer gives multiple Indent Space errors for same line

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I seem to be getting a strange situation where CodeSniffer is applying 2 indent space conditions on some lines of code. An example is below, where, if I set 0 indent on the line for demo purposes, it outputs the following error:

> 336 | ERROR | Line indented incorrectly; expected 4 spaces, found 0
>
> 336 | ERROR | Line indented incorrectly; expected 6 spaces, found 0

As you can see, it is expecting 4 spaces and 6 spaces on the same line. Has anyone ever seen this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code in question is enclosed in an `if else {}` block, which is in turn enclosed in an `if {}` block.

If I change the `if else` to `ifelse`, it fixes the problem, with the Indent sniff reporting correctly.